# How do I make a control header appear to the left of instead on top of a control?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, windows-10

Currently, I'm working with a ToggleSwitch in windows 10. The default position of the Header is on top of the control, but I'd like to move it to the left of the control so that the entire thing can be contained on one line.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look with  Blend to the style of the ToggleSwitch it is not just change a parameter, but I edited the template to be in one line:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ToggleSwitchStyle1" TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="154"/>
        <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="System,TranslateX"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
                    <Grid BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="12" Width="12"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ToggleStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOnTransition" From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" To="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOffTransition" From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" To="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OnToOffTransition" From="On" GeneratedDuration="0" To="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobOnToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OffToOnTransition" From="Off" GeneratedDuration="0" To="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobOffToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dragging"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Off"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="On">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="24" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ContentStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="OffContent">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OnContent">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="0,0,4,0" x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                        <ContentPresenter  x:Name="OffContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OffContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding OffContent}" Grid.Column="3" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter  x:Name="OnContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OnContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding OnContent}" Grid.Column="3" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" Margin="0,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" RadiusY="10" Grid.Row="2" RadiusX="10" Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" Width="44"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchKnobBounds" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" Height="20" Opacity="0" RadiusY="10" Grid.Row="2" RadiusX="10" Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchOnStrokeThickness}" Width="44"/>
                        <Grid x:Name="SwitchKnob" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Grid.Column="1" Width="20">
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="SwitchKnobOn" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" Height="10" Opacity="0" Width="10"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="SwitchKnobOff" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" Height="10" Width="10"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Thumb Grid.Column="1" x:Name="SwitchThumb" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                            <Thumb.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Thumb.Template>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

And then just apply the style:

```
 <ToggleSwitch Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchStyle1}" Header="Hello Windows 10"/>
```